# Angular 4: Data binding

Tags: angular, data-binding

I am trying to bind `data-target` to `'#' + entry.name + 'modal'` by doing `[data-target]="'#' + entry.name + 'modal'"` but doing so keeps throwing a template parse error `Can't bind to 'data-target' since it isn't a known property of 'button'`. I am confused why it is saying this since it is how I would always open a modal. Do I have to do it in a different way in angular?

Comment: Test `[attr.data-taget]=...`.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks a lot.

Comment: @developer033 provide it as an answer so OP can accept it :-)